# how to add ajaxslider in datalist controll

Tags: asp.net

I want to add ajax slider. But problem is that  I have added images in datalist controll.
 When i add targetcontroll id in ajax slider. Error shows target controll id not found.

Datalist Code:

```
<img alt="" src ='image/<%#Eval("Image") %>' id="imgslide" /></ItemTemplate>
```

Ajax slider:

```
  <asp:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgslide">
          </asp:SlideShowExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use JQuery SlideShow in asp.net. I think both are same... If its cool then see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787207/i-want-to-program-a-slideshow-in-asp-net/12787392#12787392)